# Unable to add views after RecyclerView in NestedScrollView

Tags: android

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cat_list_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Popular Categories"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:fontFamily="@fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@id/cat_list_title"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/list"
            android:id="@+id/stats_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stats"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="10sp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How do I add the TextView after the RecyclerView in the NestedScrollView?
When I added it, it doesnt show up... However, the textView above the RecyclerView works and is visible

Comment: Change RelativeLayout to Lineat Layout, looks like you have not used relative layout features. So, the text view hiding behind the list view.

Comment: @SaiPrasad I did use `android:layout_below="@id/list"`, just had to change the `match_parent` of RecyclerView to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in `RecyclerView`

replace

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cat_list_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Popular Categories"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="@fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/cat_list_title"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/list"
        android:id="@+id/stats_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stats"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:padding="10sp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set `RecyclerView` height `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. and change your needs according.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cat_list_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Popular Categories"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="@fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/cat_list_title"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/list"
        android:id="@+id/stats_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stats"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:padding="10sp"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks that might work if I didnt have an AppBarLayout.. but in my condition, it didnt work

Comment: you can only added relative layout in parent your xml code and inside relative layout you can add any view button,textview etc.